# Android 11 Pinned Shortcuts - is there a way to pin a shortcut inside a directory?

Tags: android, shortcut, android-launcher

Relevant docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html

The following method:
`shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut()`
Creates a shortcut at the launcher(home) screen.

Is there a way to create a shortcut, for example, inside a directory on the launcher? Or any other specific location?